# Apache port is changing when sending iOS push notification

Tags: apache, notifications, port

I'm using xampp with apache.
I have a script that sends push notification to a iOS mobile app. 
When I send the notification, the port of the apache is changing from 80 to something like 5223 or 5223132. And after that the notifications are not sent anymore, I have to restart apache to comeback to port 80.

Is there a way to enforce apache to not change it's port? 
Or what it may be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: So you are pushing _form_ Apache _to_ the mobile device – so that’s an _outgoing_ connection for the server, so why _should_ Apache use port 80 for that?

Comment: I know but, after the notification is sent, apache doesn't come back to port 80 and I cannot send other notifications if I don't restart

Comment: What does “come back to port 80” even mean …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xampp was showing in the pannel, that the port was changing. But everything was ok. I had a problem in the code